# Android debug - crash on deleting TextView,Button and Layout

Tags: android

My app crashes when I click the button to delete a TextView, Button and LinearLayout. Here is the logcat report. It crashes right on when i want to removeView on line 118:

```
        tasklayout.removeView(taskbutton);

05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.com.com.addtask.deltask(addtask.java:118)
05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.com.com.addtask$2.onClick(addtask.java:65)
05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-19 14:35:58.222: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
```

Here is the onClickListner and the deltask void

```
    Button delt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelete1);
    delt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            deltask(v);
        }
    });

public void deltask(View v) {

    SharedPreferences datatask;
    datatask = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    int tnum = datatask.getInt("tasknumber", 1);
    int layoutnum = 1000 + tnum;
    int textviewnum = 1100 + tnum;
    int buttonviewnum = 1200 + tnum;

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.taskll);
    LinearLayout tasklayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(layoutnum);
    TextView tasktv = (TextView) findViewById(textviewnum);
    Button taskbutton = (Button) findViewById(buttonviewnum);

    tasklayout.removeView(taskbutton);
    tasklayout.removeView(tasktv);
    layout.removeView(tasklayout);

}
```

someone help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are messing up the view ids and trying to find something that isn't actually there. Instead of assigning ids programatically, it may be best to set tags instead and use `findViewByTag`.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it still does not work :/ if you have any other ideas I would love to hear them!

Comment: @Nicholas: Not really... The error is clear `tasklayout` is `null` as its not being found, there is no view with that id.

Answer (score 3):

Try intializing all the layout and textviews that is findviewbyiD outside the function.Do it globaly I think it may work after doing the same.Intializing it in the oncreate may solve the issue.